# How to create a string type tensor in tensorflow C api?

Tags: c, tensorflow

What exactly should the `data` below in the parameter list be?

```
TF_Tensor* tensorStr = TF_NewTensor(TF_STRING, nullptr, 0, &data[0], 8, no_op, nullptr);
```

I tried:

```
char * data = "blah";
char* data[] = {"blah"};
char data[1][4] = {{'b','l','a','h'}};
```

all out of luck. When feed into input. I always get :

```
Malformed TF_STRING tensor; element 0 out of range
```

Answer (score 4):

Example of valid (but a bit ugly) code which creates a string tensor:

```
std::string input_str = "abracdabra";  // any input string
size_t encoded_size = TF_StringEncodedSize(input_str.size());
size_t total_size = 8 + encoded_size;  // 8 extra bytes - for start_offset 
char *input_encoded = (char*)malloc(total_size);
for (int i =0; i < 8; ++i) {  // fills start_offset
    input_encoded[i] = 0;
}
TF_StringEncode(input_str.c_str(), input_str.size(), input_encoded+8, encoded_size, status); // fills the rest of tensor data
if (TF_GetCode(status) != TF_OK){
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: something wrong with encoding: %s", TF_Message(status));
    return 1;
}
TF_Tensor* input = TF_NewTensor(TF_STRING, NULL, 0, input_encoded, total_size, &Deallocator, 0);
```

Why it works: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/c/c_api.h#L213  According to this link, data for string tensor consists of two parts. The last one is input string encoded via TF_StringEncode function. The first one is array 'start_offset', I don't completely understand its role, but looks like eight zeros do the trick)

Another example of tensor creation could be found in C API tests: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/c/c_api_test.cc#L1934

Comment: a very useful example. but seems that this example only takes consideration of the case of a single string, how to create a tensor contains a list of string, like ['ab', 'abc', 'cc']?

Answer (score 1):

Unless a Tensor is a scalar (holding just a single number) you need to pass in dimensions information. You're passing in nullptr and zero for the dims in your current code, which is why it's raising an error. You can see an example of how to call TF_NewTensor for a string here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/c/c_api.cc#L441

Comment: But what is the dimension of a string if it's not a scalar?

Comment: `int64_t dims[] = {1};` still get the same error.  with `int64_t dims[] = {4};` I got: Malformed TF_STRING tensor; too short to hold number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

For TF2.xxx

```
const char* str = "Hello, World!";
int NumInputs = 1;    
TF_Tensor** InputValues = (TF_Tensor**)malloc(sizeof(TF_Tensor*)*NumInputs);

TF_TString* s0 = malloc(sizeof(TF_TString) * strlen(str));
TF_StringInit(s0);

TF_StringCopy(s0, str, strlen(str));

int ndims = 1;
int64_t dims[] = {1};    
int ndata = sizeof(TF_TString) * strlen(str);

TF_Tensor* str_tensor = TF_NewTensor(TF_STRING, dims, ndims, s0, ndata, &NoOpDeallocator, 0);
```